# Convert M3U IPTV playlist to Coaxial cable signal

Tags: television

Is there a device which you can feed an IPTV playlist to and outputs the signal via a coaxial cable, to be able to use on any new/old TV in the house?

Context: I have internet subscription but no cable TV subscription. My provider offers some of its channels for free via IPTV for all its internet users. I want to be able to watch those channels using my existing coax cabling, and without set-top-boxes.

Preferably I should be able to use 2 TVs at the same time each tuned to a different channel. If not, then 1 client will suffice. However, I want the TV to behave as it normally would using a real cable TV (e.g. use its remote, use its built-in settings to reorder the channels)

Thanks.

PS: Sorry if this is the wrong place where I ask this question. I'm really confused as to which StackExchange site I should ask this question on. There's too many of them.